# How to limit choices to Foreign keys in Django admin

Tags: django, foreign-keys, admin

I run into a problem when using the Django admin. I'm building a small ScrumBoard. It has projects, with statuses, stories and tasks.

Consider the following model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Project')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Projects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64) # e.g. Todo, In progress, Testing Done
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Status')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Statuses')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Story(models.Model):
    """Unit of work to be done for the sprint. Can consist out of smaller tasks"""
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Story')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Stories')

    # represent a story with it's title
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problem: when an admin user creates a story he will see statuses from all the projects instead of the status from one project.

Comment: It's normal, and even if you custom your admin, on creation you can't guess what statuses must be listed

Comment: I understand the problem: isn't there a way to pre select the project (for example in a querystring or via http post) and then show the rest of the status form without the ability to select another project.

Comment: you can use subset after creation (on modification) by customizing your admin modelform.

Comment: Could you provide a code example based on the subset approach?
Is it similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839831/django-admin-many-to-many-subset)?

Comment: You can avoid making your own modelform class, but as status is required, the creation won't work as expected. (otherwise, you could remove the field on creation form as most fields of django users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter statuses by project, you need your story to already exist so django know which project we are talking about. If you set status nullalble, you can do like this (implying, you do save and continue on first save to set status)

```
class StatusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(StatusAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj and obj.project:
            form.base_fields['status'].queryset = \
                form.base_fields['status'].queryset.filter(project=obj.project)
        elif obj is None and 'status' in form.base_fields: # on creation
            del form.base_fields['status']
        return form
```

Comment: You solution seems to "almost" work.  But get_form() gets called twice.

Comment: I use a comparable code (in fact complex mixins doing that with far more automation but implying some specific definitions on models as a for_user class method…) in production without problems. Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: As you say it's called twice, I suppose your problem is on the del line. You can't use my snippet with a custom form. (As I override every time default behaviour) (# form = MyForm). Admin default behaviour is to generate a new FormClass each time and I rely on it. (I added a quick edit to avoid double del)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

Comment: Could you show an example how to use this in admin?